# Customer Sign Up - after form submition, just reloads the page and no customer created

Tags: customer, magento2.2.2, registration

After filling all fields in Registration form on frontend (Customer Sign Up page) - the page just updates with empty fields and customer not being created. Its fresh install, default luma theme. And no errors in logs

Comment: Do you use a fresh install?

Comment: Yes. Freash, no third-party modules, luma theme

Comment: Can you give me your base url?

Comment: its on localhost..

Comment: This is the issue. Don't try to use localhost as Top Level Domain. Try to use another. You can config others: mage2.loc, magento.loc....

Comment: Strangely, with virtualhost it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One of the comments on your question seems to be correct. I've just run into this problem for the first time setting up a local docker environment for magento cloud 2.2.4.

### Symptoms

Tried to fill out and submit customer account create form, but page just appears to reload with no messages

### My Configuration

I had the the base urls set to: https://localhost/

### Attempts To Fix

Historically I've used the .dev top-level domain with no problems. When I tried to use one this time, the browser (Chrome in my case) refuses to load the site and wouldn't let me proceed

### Solution

Used a different top-level domain, such as .loc

### References

Here is an article I quickly found with some more information about why it can no longer be done:

https://medium.engineering/use-a-dev-domain-not-anymore-95219778e6fd